# error when trying to remove last character of a string

Tags: c#, string, trim

I am trying to remove the last `","` of a string however i am getting an error stating that

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'StartIndex cannot be less than zero.

the string is written to the file fine but it breaks when running with the above error. I'm unsure as to why this is happening, any suggestions would be appreciated.

the code I am using is as follows

```
for (int z = 0; z <= totalNumberOfCaves; z++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfCaves && connectionStack.Count > 0; i++)
        {
            connectionData.Add(int.Parse(connectionStack.Pop()));
        }
        string fileName2 = @"D:\UNI\Year 5\AI - SET09122\SET09122 - CW1\WriteConnectionData.txt";
        string writeUnEditedData = "";        
        foreach (int s in connectionData)
        {
            writeUnEditedData += (s + ",");
        }
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fileName2))
    {
        string writeData = writeUnEditedData.Remove(writeUnEditedData.Length - 1);
        sw.Write("{ " + writeData + " }," + Environment.NewLine);            
    }
    connectionData.Clear();
}
```

Comment: Just a guess: shouldn't `z <= totalNumberOfCaves` rather be `z < totalNumberOfCaves`

Comment: `writeUnEditedData = string.Join(",", s);` instead of the loop

Comment: @RenéVogt damn, I'd completely over looked that. that's done the job, Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Appending `string` in a loop:

```
    foreach (int s in connectionData)
    {
        writeUnEditedData += (s + ",");
    }
```

is *not* a good idea. Put `Join`:

```
    writeUnEditedData = string.Join(",", connectionData);
```

Having this done, you don't have to remove anything:

```
 using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fileName2))
 { 
     // No Remove here
     string writeData = writeUnEditedData;
     ...
```

Comment: OP can also delete the `.Remove` code, as it will not be necessary anymore

Answer (score 5):

Try `string.TrimEnd()`:

```
writeUnEditedData = writeUnEditedData.TrimEnd(',');
```

Comment: @MongZhu: it does, because it happens precisely because an attempt is made to remove a comma that's not there by indexing the last character of an empty string. `TrimEnd` avoids this (but using `Join` so no trimming is necessary is obviously superior).

Comment: You won't get an exception using this. As it is only looking for ","

Answer (score 2):

Add a check to see if writeUnEditedData is not an empty string before you do the Remove. An empty string will results in a Remove(-1) which I would assume would throw an error that the StartIndex cannot be less then 0.

Comment: @MongZhu, it may be; if the `writeUnEditedData` is an empty string, it will throw that exception too

Answer (score 1):

This usually means that the string is empty.

Try to put this guard code in:

```
string writeData = string.IsNullOrEmpty(writeUnEditedData)
    ? string.Empty
    : writeUnEditedData.Remove(writeUnEditedData.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can improve on this pattern:

```
string writeUnEditedData = "";        
foreach (int s in connectionData)
{
    writeUnEditedData += (s + ",");
}
```

to avoid adding the comma in the first place:

```
string delimiter = "";
string writeUnEditedData = "";        
foreach (int s in connectionData)
{
    writeUnEditedData += $"{delimiter}{s}";
    delimiter = ",";
}
```

or with a `StringBuilder`... though contrary to popular belief this only helps if the `connectionData` collection is kinda big:

```
string delimiter = "";
var writeUnEditedData = new StringBuilder();        
foreach (int s in connectionData)
{
    writeUnEditedData.Append(delimiter).Append(s);
    delimiter = ",";
}
```

Even better still, stream the whole thing, to avoid needing all that extra memory and processing:

```
string fileName2 = @"D:\UNI\Year 5\AI - SET09122\SET09122 - CW1\WriteConnectionData.txt";
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName2, true))
{
    for (int z = 0; z <= totalNumberOfCaves; z++)
    {
        string delimiter = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < totalNumberOfCaves && connectionStack.Count > 0; i++)
        {
            sw.Write(delimiter);
            sw.Write(connectionStack.Pop());
            delimiter = ",";
        }
        sw.Write(Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```